# ServiceStack LoCode datetime

Tags: servicestack

Attempting to use ServiceStack LoCode to use database first to allow users to edit data in an existing database table.  The table has a couple DateTime fields.  I don't see in the documentation how to format a datetime field when using database first mode.  The demo application (https://northwind.locode.dev/) appears to just use a string field for any date values instead of an actual DateTime(?...)

When the data renders on screen the values appears as "2020-01-01T00:00:00.0000000", which would be usable - but when in row edit mode the error from the browser trying to bind to the html input field is:

```
The specified value "2020-01-01T00:00:00.0000000" does not conform to the required format, "yyyy-MM-dd".
```

The value in the Date Input does not load and it is always empty when trying to edit date fields using LoCode as Database first.  Can somebody help me find the documentation to set up my fields to be able to edit the DateTime values?  Below is the best guess I could come up with - seeing in the documentation that it is possible to format for a couple predefined types...

```
if (type.Name == "PolicyMatchFacility") 
{
    type.Property("StartDate").AddAttribute(new FormatAttribute("MM/dd/yyyy"));
}
```

Comment: After stepping away from the keyboard - this is happening because I am overriding the default DateTime json Serialization in ServiceStack - so the real question instead is how we can have the rest of the app use one set of DateTime serialization rules and the LoCode use the other...

Comment: Locode is just calling your existing APIs, they can't be configured separately for Locode. What is your custom JSON configuration and are you using the latest ServiceStack v6.8?

Comment: For reasons we are changing the default DateTime serialization format - and that is what is causing downstreams to have issues consuming that data...  At this point I suspect the easiest solution will be to isolate our LoDash instance into a separate app that doesn't require the custom serialization logic for our other workflows.  I had completely forgotten about our custom serialization logic until taking a few seconds away from the keyboard...

JsConfig<DateTime>.SerializeFn = time => "{0:o}{1}".FormatWith(new DateTime(time.Ticks), time.Kind == DateTimeKind.Utc ? "Z" : "");

Comment: Yeah if that's an option, isolating Locode (and other built-in UIs) in a separate App without custom serialization will be the path of less friction in future.

Answer (score 1):

LoCode like the rest of ServiceStack uses the common settings for JsonSerialization - string formats for Dates are coming from JsConfig.SerializeFn and downstream items expect data to be in a format they can handle.